# How do I create geometry in SceneKit?

Tags: opengl, vertex

I have been experimenting with Apple's new SceneKit for fun, but I cannot seem to figure out how to input vertex data without loading a `.dae` file.

Does anybody who has been testing SceneKit have any idea how to set or modify vertex data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SceneKit is primarily a scene graph API and it isn't designed to be a complete solution for all your rendering needs; it's designed to augment existing APIs such as GLKit and CoreAnimation.

Primarily the focus of the API is loading serialized geometry assets (`.dae` files) and organizing them in a scene graph. There aren't very many robust alternative methods to get geometry into the API.

However, you may find SCNGeometry's [geometryWithSources:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometry_Class/Reference/SCNGeometry.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012000-CLSCHSCNGeometry-SW16) selector to be what you need. [Here's an example](http://www.cleoag.ru/2013/01/17/how-create-geometry-scenekit/) in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an article on this topic which you might find helpful, it explains the basic of creating custom **SceneKit geometry**: http://sound-of-silence.com/?article=20161108

There is also related example code of creating custom geometry with SceneKit for deformable terrain meshes in that post, the code can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/matthewreagan/TerrainMesh3D

Comment: If you think the article helps towards answering the question, you should summarise the key points. While you can provide external links for additional reading, an answer must answer the actual question without the need to follow links, so that your answer persists even if the link breaks. If you feel the article *doesn't* actually answer the question, perhaps this would be better as a comment.